# How to change highmap bubble color

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

I am trying to color the bubbles based on the name of the cities. Something like if this.point.capital == Montgomery & this.point.capital == Juneau; color = "red". But I cannot add this if function to the color attribute. Can you help me out?

Thanks!!!!

```
series: [{
            name: 'Basemap',
            mapData: map,
            borderColor: '#606060',
            nullColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.2)',
            showInLegend: false
        }, {
            name: 'Separators',
            type: 'mapline',
            data: H.geojson(map, 'mapline'),
            color: '#101010',
            enableMouseTracking: false
        }, {
            type: 'mapbubble',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.capital}'
            },
            name: 'Cities',
            data: data,
            maxSize: '12%',
            color: H.getOptions().colors[0]
        }]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oufwhmz0/

Answer (score 3):

Do this for each bubble individually (not the series as a whole) in the `data` array prior to initiating the chart. For example extending your code ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oufwhmz0/1/)):

```
function determineColor(entry) {
    if(entry.capital == "Montgomery")
        return "#FF00FF";
    else if(entry.capital == "Salt Lake City")
        return "#00FF00";
    return null;
}

// Add series with state capital bubbles
$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=us-capitals.json&callback=?', function (json) {
    var data = [];
    $.each(json, function (ix, entry) {
        entry.z = entry.population;
        entry.color = determineColor(entry); // Added
        data.push(entry);
    });

    // ... rest as usual
});
```

This just sets the `color` for each `entry` (which will be a bubble), as defined by the `determineColor` function.

Comment: Thank you! Then, how can I change the hover over to the right color?